# Marker Clustering,Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

```
  <h1>Explore Ireland with me!</h1>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
    function initMap(){
      // map options
      var options = {
        zoom:7,
        center:{lat:53.3938131, lng:-7.858913}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),options);
      // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.

      //Add marker
      var markers = [

        //Dublin
        {
          coords:{lat:53.338741, lng:-6.261563},
          iconImage:'assets/img/places/stparkdublin.png',
          content:'<h1>St Stephen’s Green</h1>'+ '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>http://ststephensgreenpark.ie/</a>'
        },
        {
          coords:{lat:53.3755012,lng:-6.2735677},
          iconImage:'assets/img/places/botanic garden.png',
          content:'<h1>Botanic Garden</h1>' + '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>http://botanicgardens.ie/</a>'
        },
        {
          coords:{lat:53.355998576, lng:-6.32166538},
          iconImage:'assets/img/places/stparkdublin.png',////////////////////add picture
          content:'<h1>Phoenix Park</h1>' + '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>http://phoenixpark.ie/</a>'
        },
        {
          coords:{lat:53.460259, lng:-6.219985},
          iconImage:'assets/img/places/swordscastle.png',
          content:'<h1>Swords Castle</h1>'+ '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://swordscastle.events/</a>'
        },
        {
          coords:{lat:53.37923, lng:-6.07201},
          iconImage:'assets/img/places/Howth.png',
          content:'<h1>Howth</h1>'+ '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>http://www.visithowth.ie/</a>'
        },
        {
          coords:{lat:55.1364, lng:-7.456},
          iconImage:'assets/img/places/buncrana1.png',
          content:'<h1>Buncrana</h1>'+ '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buncrana</a>'
        },

        {
          coords:{lat:53.152999388, lng:-6.1499994},
          iconImage:'assets/img/places/sugarloaf_icon.png',
          content:'<h1>Great sugar loaf</h1>'+ '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>http://visitwicklow.ie/item/the-sugarloaf-trail/</a>'
        },
        {
          coords:{lat:52.0058, lng:-9.5562},
          iconImage:'assets/img/places/killarney.png',
          content:'<h1>Killarney National Park </h1>'+ '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://www.killarneynationalpark.ie/</a>'
        },
        {
          coords:{lat:51.942662896, lng:-9.917162998},
          iconImage:'assets/img/places/clifs.png',
          content:'<h1>Ring of Kerry</h1>'+ '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://ringofkerrytourism.com/</a>'
        },
        {
          coords:{lat:52.679, lng:-7.814},
          iconImage:'assets/img/places/clifs.png',//add picture!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
          content:'<h1>Thurles</h1>'+ '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://www.tipperary.com/thurles</a>'
        },
        {
          coords:{lat:52.348, lng:-6.517},
          iconImage:'assets/img/places/wexford museum.png',
          content:'<h1>Irish National Heritage Park</h1>'+ '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>http://www.irishheritage.ie/</a>'
        },
        {
          coords:{lat:53.018, lng:-6.398},
          iconImage:'assets/img/places/wicklow.png',
          content:'<h1> Wicklow Mountains National Park</h1>'+ '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://www.wicklowmountainsnationalpark.ie/</a>'
        },
        {
          coords:{lat:53.011299, lng:   -6.326156},
          iconImage:'assets/img/places/glendalough.png',
          content:'<h1> Glendalough </h1>'+ '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>http://www.glendalough.ie/</a>'
        },
        {
          coords:{lat:53.1876492494, lng:-6.083832998},
          iconImage:'assets/img/places/Bray.png',
          content:'<h1> Bray</h1>'+ '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>http://www.bray.ie/</a>'
        },
        {
          coords:{lat:53.144, lng: -6.072},
          iconImage:'assets/img/places/greystones.png',
          content:'<h1>Greystones</h1>'+ '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>http://visitwicklow.ie/item/greystones/</a>'
        },
        {
          coords:{lat:52.518664592, lng:-7.887329784},
          iconImage:'assets/img/places/Cashel.png',
          content:'<h1>Rock of Cashel</h1>'+ '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://www.cashel.ie/</a>'
        },
        {
          coords:{lat:52.6477, lng: -7.2561},
          iconImage:'assets/img/places/kilkenny.png',
          content:'<h1>Killenny</h1>'+ '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://visitkilkenny.ie/</a>'
        },
        //cork
        {
          coords:{lat:51.902694, lng:-8.4767},
          iconImage:'assets/img/places/butterCork.png',
          content:'<h1>Museum of Butter</h1>'+ '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>http://thebuttermuseum.com/</a>'
        },
        {
          coords:{lat:51.89953, lng:-8.499022},
          iconImage:'assets/img/places/prisoncork.png',
          content:'<h1>Cork City Gaol</h1>'+'<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://corkcitygaol.com/</a>'
        },

        {
          coords:{lat:53.4513204, lng:-6.140871},
          iconImage:'assets/img/places/malahideB.png',
          content:'<h1>Malahide</h1>'+'<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://www.malahide.ie/</a>'
        },

        {
          coords:{lat:53.2839577, lng:-9.0837658},
          iconImage:'assets/img/places/galway.png',
          content:'<h1>Galway</h1>'+'<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://www.galwaytourism.ie/</a>'
        },
        {
          coords:{lat:53.470580, lng:-6.122405},
          iconImage:'assets/img/places/galway.png',
          content:'<h1>Donabate Beach</h1>'+'<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donabate</a>'
        },
        {
          coords:{lat:52.9713299, lng:-9.4300415},
          iconImage:'assets/img/places/clifsofmoher.png',
          content:'<h1>Donabate Beach</h1>'+'<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://www.cliffsofmoher.ie/</a>'
        },
        {
          coords:{lat:51.8960528, lng:-8.4980693},
          iconImage:'assets/img/places/Cork.png',
          content:'<h1>Cork</h1>'+'<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://purecork.ie/</a>'
        },
        {
          coords:{lat:53.3667776, lng:-6.5064198},
          iconImage:'assets/img/places/Leixlip.png',
          content:'<h1>Leixlip</h1>'+'<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leixlip</a>'
        },
        {
          coords:{lat:53.1654628, lng:-6.125499},
          iconImage:'assets/img/places/littlesugarloaf.png',
          content:'<h1>Little Sugar Loaf</h1>'+'<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://www.greystonesguide.ie/little-sugar-loafs-big-day/</a>'
        },
        {
          coords:{lat:53.5474019, lng:-6.0933048},
          iconImage:'assets/img/places/rockabill view.png',
          content:'<h1>Rockabill View</h1>'+'<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>http://www.skerriesseatours.ie/trips.html</a>'
        },
        {
          coords:{lat:52.3337499, lng:-6.4906996},
          iconImage:'assets/img/places/wexford.png',
          content:'<h1>Wexford</h1>'+'<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://www.visitwexford.ie/</a>'
        },
      ];

      // Loop through markers
      for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
        addMarker(markers[i]);

      }




      //Add MArker function
      function addMarker(props){
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position:props.coords,
          map:map,

        });

        if(props.iconImage){
          marker.setIcon(props.iconImage);
        }

        //Check content
        if(props.content){
          var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content:props.content
          });
          marker.addListener('click',function(){
            infoWindow.open(map,marker);
          });
        }
      }
      var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
          {imagePath: });
    }
  </script>
```

I want to add marker clustering to my code. I have few custom markers, and info windows. But I don't know how to implement marker clustering. Everything works fine with my code. But For a better look I want to add this option. I check this web to see how can I add them to my code https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering. I put the marker clustering file onto my website and added the link into my code, but now I struggle where to put `var markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(...)` so it works properly.

Comment: There is example in official documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-clustering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have obvious syntax errors in the posted code.

1. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var` on these lines:

```
// map options
var options = {
  zoom:7,
  center:{lat:53.3938131, lng:-7.858913}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),options);
```

should be:

```
// map options
var options = {
  zoom:7,
  center:{lat:53.3938131, lng:-7.858913}
} // <===================================================================== missing "}"
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),options);
```

2. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }` on this line:

```
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
      {imagePath: });
```

either remove the `imagePath:` or add a value for it:

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, 
  {
    imagePath:
    'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
  });
```

3. The markers array passed into the `MarkerClusterer` must be an array of `google.maps.Marker` objects, create one.

```
// Loop through markers
var gmarkers = [];
for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
  gmarkers.push(addMarker(markers[i]));
}

//Add MArker function
function addMarker(props){
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position:props.coords,
    map:map,
  });
  if(props.iconImage){
    marker.setIcon(props.iconImage);
  }
  //Check content
  if(props.content){
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content:props.content
    });
    marker.addListener('click',function(){
      infoWindow.open(map,marker);
    });
  }
  return marker;
}
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, gmarkers, {
  imagePath:
  'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
  });
```

[proof of concept/working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/9ch54uxo/2/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  function initMap() {
    // map options
    var options = {
      zoom: 7,
      center: {
        lat: 53.3938131,
        lng: -7.858913
      }
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
    // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.

    //Add marker
    var markers = [

      //Dublin
      {
        coords: {
          lat: 53.338741,
          lng: -6.261563
        },
        iconImage: 'assets/img/places/stparkdublin.png',
        content: '<h1>St Stephen’s Green</h1>' + '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>http://ststephensgreenpark.ie/</a>'
      },
      {
        coords: {
          lat: 53.3755012,
          lng: -6.2735677
        },
        iconImage: 'assets/img/places/botanic garden.png',
        content: '<h1>Botanic Garden</h1>' + '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>http://botanicgardens.ie/</a>'
      },
      {
        coords: {
          lat: 53.355998576,
          lng: -6.32166538
        },
        iconImage: 'assets/img/places/stparkdublin.png', ////////////////////add picture
        content: '<h1>Phoenix Park</h1>' + '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>http://phoenixpark.ie/</a>'
      },
      {
        coords: {
          lat: 53.460259,
          lng: -6.219985
        },
        iconImage: 'assets/img/places/swordscastle.png',
        content: '<h1>Swords Castle</h1>' + '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://swordscastle.events/</a>'
      },
      {
        coords: {
          lat: 53.37923,
          lng: -6.07201
        },
        iconImage: 'assets/img/places/Howth.png',
        content: '<h1>Howth</h1>' + '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>http://www.visithowth.ie/</a>'
      },
      {
        coords: {
          lat: 55.1364,
          lng: -7.456
        },
        iconImage: 'assets/img/places/buncrana1.png',
        content: '<h1>Buncrana</h1>' + '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buncrana</a>'
      },

      {
        coords: {
          lat: 53.152999388,
          lng: -6.1499994
        },
        iconImage: 'assets/img/places/sugarloaf_icon.png',
        content: '<h1>Great sugar loaf</h1>' + '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>http://visitwicklow.ie/item/the-sugarloaf-trail/</a>'
      },
      {
        coords: {
          lat: 52.0058,
          lng: -9.5562
        },
        iconImage: 'assets/img/places/killarney.png',
        content: '<h1>Killarney National Park </h1>' + '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://www.killarneynationalpark.ie/</a>'
      },
      {
        coords: {
          lat: 51.942662896,
          lng: -9.917162998
        },
        iconImage: 'assets/img/places/clifs.png',
        content: '<h1>Ring of Kerry</h1>' + '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://ringofkerrytourism.com/</a>'
      },
      {
        coords: {
          lat: 52.679,
          lng: -7.814
        },
        iconImage: 'assets/img/places/clifs.png', //add picture!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        content: '<h1>Thurles</h1>' + '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://www.tipperary.com/thurles</a>'
      },
      {
        coords: {
          lat: 52.348,
          lng: -6.517
        },
        iconImage: 'assets/img/places/wexford museum.png',
        content: '<h1>Irish National Heritage Park</h1>' + '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>http://www.irishheritage.ie/</a>'
      },
      {
        coords: {
          lat: 53.018,
          lng: -6.398
        },
        iconImage: 'assets/img/places/wicklow.png',
        content: '<h1> Wicklow Mountains National Park</h1>' + '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://www.wicklowmountainsnationalpark.ie/</a>'
      },
      {
        coords: {
          lat: 53.011299,
          lng: -6.326156
        },
        iconImage: 'assets/img/places/glendalough.png',
        content: '<h1> Glendalough </h1>' + '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>http://www.glendalough.ie/</a>'
      },
      {
        coords: {
          lat: 53.1876492494,
          lng: -6.083832998
        },
        iconImage: 'assets/img/places/Bray.png',
        content: '<h1> Bray</h1>' + '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>http://www.bray.ie/</a>'
      },
      {
        coords: {
          lat: 53.144,
          lng: -6.072
        },
        iconImage: 'assets/img/places/greystones.png',
        content: '<h1>Greystones</h1>' + '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>http://visitwicklow.ie/item/greystones/</a>'
      },
      {
        coords: {
          lat: 52.518664592,
          lng: -7.887329784
        },
        iconImage: 'assets/img/places/Cashel.png',
        content: '<h1>Rock of Cashel</h1>' + '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://www.cashel.ie/</a>'
      },
      {
        coords: {
          lat: 52.6477,
          lng: -7.2561
        },
        iconImage: 'assets/img/places/kilkenny.png',
        content: '<h1>Killenny</h1>' + '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://visitkilkenny.ie/</a>'
      },
      //cork
      {
        coords: {
          lat: 51.902694,
          lng: -8.4767
        },
        iconImage: 'assets/img/places/butterCork.png',
        content: '<h1>Museum of Butter</h1>' + '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>http://thebuttermuseum.com/</a>'
      },
      {
        coords: {
          lat: 51.89953,
          lng: -8.499022
        },
        iconImage: 'assets/img/places/prisoncork.png',
        content: '<h1>Cork City Gaol</h1>' + '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://corkcitygaol.com/</a>'
      },

      {
        coords: {
          lat: 53.4513204,
          lng: -6.140871
        },
        iconImage: 'assets/img/places/malahideB.png',
        content: '<h1>Malahide</h1>' + '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://www.malahide.ie/</a>'
      },

      {
        coords: {
          lat: 53.2839577,
          lng: -9.0837658
        },
        iconImage: 'assets/img/places/galway.png',
        content: '<h1>Galway</h1>' + '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://www.galwaytourism.ie/</a>'
      },
      {
        coords: {
          lat: 53.470580,
          lng: -6.122405
        },
        iconImage: 'assets/img/places/galway.png',
        content: '<h1>Donabate Beach</h1>' + '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donabate</a>'
      },
      {
        coords: {
          lat: 52.9713299,
          lng: -9.4300415
        },
        iconImage: 'assets/img/places/clifsofmoher.png',
        content: '<h1>Donabate Beach</h1>' + '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://www.cliffsofmoher.ie/</a>'
      },
      {
        coords: {
          lat: 51.8960528,
          lng: -8.4980693
        },
        iconImage: 'assets/img/places/Cork.png',
        content: '<h1>Cork</h1>' + '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://purecork.ie/</a>'
      },
      {
        coords: {
          lat: 53.3667776,
          lng: -6.5064198
        },
        iconImage: 'assets/img/places/Leixlip.png',
        content: '<h1>Leixlip</h1>' + '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leixlip</a>'
      },
      {
        coords: {
          lat: 53.1654628,
          lng: -6.125499
        },
        iconImage: 'assets/img/places/littlesugarloaf.png',
        content: '<h1>Little Sugar Loaf</h1>' + '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://www.greystonesguide.ie/little-sugar-loafs-big-day/</a>'
      },
      {
        coords: {
          lat: 53.5474019,
          lng: -6.0933048
        },
        iconImage: 'assets/img/places/rockabill view.png',
        content: '<h1>Rockabill View</h1>' + '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>http://www.skerriesseatours.ie/trips.html</a>'
      },
      {
        coords: {
          lat: 52.3337499,
          lng: -6.4906996
        },
        iconImage: 'assets/img/places/wexford.png',
        content: '<h1>Wexford</h1>' + '<br>' + '<h2>Learn More</h2>' + '<a>https://www.visitwexford.ie/</a>'
      },
    ];

    // Loop through markers
    var gmarkers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      gmarkers.push(addMarker(markers[i]));

    }

    //Add MArker function
    function addMarker(props) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: props.coords,
        map: map,

      });

      /* if(props.iconImage){
        marker.setIcon(props.iconImage);
      } */

      //Check content
      if (props.content) {
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: props.content
        });
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
          infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
      }
      return marker;
    }
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, gmarkers, {
      imagePath: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m'
    });
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap)
</script>
```